# What is Beta badge, How to achieve it

Tags: discussion, badges, beta-phase, support

[image]

I am looking forward for the **badge - Beta**, How i can **actively** participate in Beta, I don't know what do they mean by it.

I can't see any link about it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) or [How to participate in beta?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82399/how-to-participate-in-beta)

Comment: You can't get the badge for a site that is already public. You need to support a site proposal on Area 51; then participate in the private beta once the site is launched.

Comment: @animuson I think there is a topic somewhere already about this badge on it's own

Comment: @Ian even so, that other topic should be closed as dupe too. Here on Meta when question has answer in a [meta-tag:faq] post it should be closed as dupe of that faq.

Answer (score 3):

If you have not participated in the private beta of a site, you cannot earn the badge.

For Stack Overflow, the private beta ended almost 4 years ago.

This badge is similar to the [precognitive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/131/precognitive) badge (Followed the Area 51 proposal for this site before it entered the commitment phase.), which will never be earned on sites such as Stack Overflow that predate Area 51.

---

To answer your questions as they pertain to sites currently on Area 51 - after a site gets accepted, it will go through a private beta phase. If you are part of that phase and participate enough to earn the beta badge, it is yours. Badges are taken away only if we confirm they were earned through fraud (say using sock puppets, voting rings etc) - so even if your participation levels drop during the private beta, you will retain the badge if you earned it.

Comment: If i earn it, do i lose the badge if they find me less active/ inactive on beta

Comment: @Ðeepak - I don't follow. Being active during the private beta period is a binary - you either were, or were not. There is no try.

Comment: @Ðeepak no, once you earn a badge you never lose it.

Comment: @Ðeepak: I think you misunderstand. There is no beta for Stack Overflow anymore. It's impossible to earn this badge if you don't already have it.

Comment: @hammar I don't think he means Stack Overflow, he's following [this Area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53951/biohacking).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: In that case, there is no beta _yet_.

Comment: @hammar true, but there will be if the site will go through Beta then live. The question is valid, though duplicate.

Comment: Is Beta attainable

Comment: @Ðeepak - Yes, in sites that are in private Beta **right now**, or that are proposals on Area 51 that will be accepted and promoted to private betas.

Comment: What about Precognitive Badge, there is nobody here with this badge

Comment: @Ðeepak The precognitive badge was never attainable on Stack Overflow, it's only attainable on SE 2.0 sites. Why don't we remove it then? Well, it's a little reminder that you can't (and shouldn't try to) win them all.

Comment: @Yannis , Then why it is here

Comment: @Ðeepak - See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71737/140505) for why.

Answer (score 0):

The Beta badge is for people who were with any new StackExchange site when it first started. It is not possible to earn this badge if you were not an early adopter.